# RestKit: Multiple RKClients / Changing baseURL

Tags: restkit, base-url

I initialize RKClient's sharedClient in my application delegate in applicationDidFinishLaunching and it works great. I am using this clients destination URL for most of the application, however at 1 point, in 1 class (Player), I need to load user's avatars from gravatar.com. So, I had the Player class define it's own RKClient and conform to the RKRequestDelegate protocol. It then makes the request, through this new RKClient instantiation and sets the delegate of the request to self. The problem is that I never receive a response; that is

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
```

Is never called. Here is the whole code sample:

```
//  Player.m

#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

# pragma mark - Accessor Synthesizers

@synthesize identifier = _identifier;
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize story = _story;
@synthesize emailHash = _emailHash;
@synthesize pointPercentage = _pointPercentage;
@synthesize hitPercentage = _hitPercentage;
@synthesize lastCups = _lastCups;
@synthesize shotCount = _shotCount;
@synthesize hitCount = _hitCount;
@synthesize wins = _wins;
@synthesize losses = _losses;
@synthesize gravatar = _gravatar;

# pragma mark - Instance Methods

- (void)getGravatar {
    RKClient *gClient = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gravatar.com"]];
    NSString *path = [self gravatarLink];
    NSLog(@"Getting Gravatar With Link: http://gravatar.com%@", path);
    [gClient get:path delegate:self];
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{Season: [id=%i, name=%@, story=%@ ]}", _identifier, _name, _story];
}

# pragma mark - RKRequest Delegate Methods

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Gravatar Back: %@", response.bodyAsString);
    self.gravatar = response.body;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GravatarLoaded" object:self];
}

# pragma mark - Private Methods

- (NSString *)gravatarLink {
    NSString  *path;
    path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/avatar/%@?d=monsterid&r=x", _emailHash];
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]==2)
        return [path stringByAppendingString:@"&s=200"];
    else
        return [path stringByAppendingString:@"&s=100"];
}

@end
```

Also, I have tried changing the base URL of the sharedClient and just using the sharedClient for the gravatar requests. But whenever I try to change the baseURL property of the RKClient sharedClient, either of these ways:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] setBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gravatar.com"]];
```

or

```
[RKClient sharedClient].baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gravatar.com"];
```

I get a runtime error:

```
2012-04-07 15:37:23.565 MLP[34403:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL URLByAppendingResourcePath:queryParameters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bcdd50'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b7c022 0x1f58cd6 0x1b7dcbd 0x1ae2ed0 0x1ae2cb2 0x23eb5 0x24032 0x6ddb 0xdda2 0xc465c5 0xc467fa 0x14db85d 0x1b50936 0x1b503d7 0x1ab3790 0x1ab2d84 0x1ab2c9b 0x20407d8 0x204088a 0xbb5626 0x27cd 0x2735)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] setBaseURL:[RKURL URLWithString:@"http://gravatar.com"]];
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `clientWithBaseURL:` method expects an `NSString`, not a `NSURL`. Try to use

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] setBaseURL:@"http://gravatar.com"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to go to Targets-> build Settings —> other Linker Flags

As specified in the RestKit Tutorial we changed added a flag called “-ObjC-all_load” now edit that to just display “-ObjC”

this must wok for you.